# Steps to Install Hubot in Slack using Digitalocean

Tags: heroku, digital-ocean, hubot, slack

I am pretty new in Slack and Hubot so I could only find solutions by searching. Recently I just want to use them to help me to deploy my website and do some other small services. But my server is on Digitalocean. The problem is that there is little information on the web about how to deploy Hubot in Digitalocean like that in Heroku. I only find this link but it's hard to follow and understand for rookie like me.
https://gist.github.com/trdarr/9212351

So I am wondering whether there is a detailed solution that deploying Hubot in Digitalocean and installing it with Slack.

I'd be very greatful if anyone can help me with this issue. Thanks!

Comment: What role does Heroku play in here?

Answer (score 0):

DigitalOcean's [Heartbot](http://valentines.digitalocean.com/) will give you a super easy start. Deployment gets a little trickier (currently working on that).